# Variable inside optional variable

Tags: swift

I have got something like this:

`let index = row.section?.index ?? -1`

What is `row.section` is nil? 
Please, help me to understand how this line works?

This is easy to understand `locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()` : method will be executed is `locationManager` is not `nil`. But while assignment optional variable into notnull instance is confusing me.

Comment: it means that if row.section?.index is nil, index will be equal to -1

Comment: What is `row.section` is nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

The nil-coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must match the type that is stored inside a.

In this case, if row.section is nil, the entire expression (row.section?.index) is nil, therefore index will be set to -1

This line `let index = row.section?.index` should be incorrect. It must be wrapped into `let index = (row.section?.index)!`